# No puedo cargar imagen en el codigo jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Buenas.
Estoy pasandole los datos de jquery al html para que los muestre y la imagen no me la esta cargando.

Este es el codigo:

```
 dataType: "json",
            url: "/Home/filtro",
            data: { tran: transaccion, loca: loca, barrio: barrio, tipo: tipo },
            success: function (data) {
                var c = data.length;
                var contenido = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                    obLista = data[i];
                    contenido += "<div class='col-md-3'>";
                    contenido += "<img src='~/Imagenes/Inmuebles/" + obLista.imagen + "' class='img-responsive' width='800' height='600'>";
                    contenido += "</div>"
                    contenido += "<h3 >" + obLista.tipo + " </h3>";
                    contenido += "<h5 >" + obLista.localidad + " </h5>";
                    contenido += "<h5 >" + obLista.barrio + " </h5>";

                }
                var f = document.getElementById("f");
                f.innerHTML = contenido;
```

No se si estoy hacieno bien, cualquier recomendacion me seria util.
Saludos

Comment: Deberías reducir el ámbito de la pregunta; con ese código no se sabe si falla la llamada en el servidor o algo de tu lógica. Por ejemplo, añadiendo `alert()` para ver los valores de `data`, `contenido`, etc., y ver dónde es que el programa deja de comportarse como debería.

Comment: Lo primero haz una llamada al servicio web y verifica que el json que te retorna es correcto. success:function(data){ console.log(data);
} Mira a ver si el nombre de imagen es correcto.